# Shared service for Electron and Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, electron

Can I access angular 4 services outside of angular? Background: I need a shared service between angular and electron.

On angular side my service looks like:

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedDemoService {
 test() { console.log(123); }
}
```

On electron side I am able to access angular like this:

```
require('@angular/core')
```

But how to access the SharedDemoService?

Comment: I'm not familiar with electron setup but I think you should be able to just require any "file" from a folder, so perhaps require("path/to/shared-demo-service") should work, have you tried that?

Comment: No, but I do not think this could work because what I need is the service provided by the dependency injection.

Comment: I don't think that would work. Why not write your `sharedDemoService` logic  into a generic module (javascript module, not angular module) , and then import it from both angular and also electron?

Comment: This is one possible solution. I just hoped there would be an angular-way solution.